# How to use "quickly run" and pass command-line arguments?

Tags: command-line, application-development, python, quickly

I'm trying to implement command-line arguments in https://launchpad.net/wakeonplan to use them in static quicklist but I can't test them because `quickly run` doesn't pass arguments to the script and `bin/wakeonplan` can't find settings location:

```
(process:18244): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'net.launchpad.wakeonplan' is not installed
```

P.S. I haven't yet pushed the latest code to the branch because it's highly experimental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help:

> $ quickly run help
>
> Runs your application. This is the best way to try test it out
>   while you are developing it. It starts up the main project window.
>
> $ quickly run -- values -
>   to pass '-whatever' and 'values' to the executed program. Without that
>   if you use for instance --help, it would be Quickly help and not your
>   program one.

So for instance, I have a program, that I import sys and add the following to the finish_initializing function:

```
print sys.argv
```

I then run from the command line:

```
quickly run -- param1=value1 param2=value2
```

Which then outputs:

> ['bin/ui-test', 'param1=value1', 'param2=value2']

Comment: It must've been some bugs in the script itself, thanks :)